# Spark: Convert String to spark.sql.types object in scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a Array of String `{"StringType", IntegerType, "LongType", "StringType"}` in scala.
And i need to covert each String to spark.sql.types object while iterating

for example:

```
StringType = spark.sql.types.StringType
IntegerType = spark.sql.types.IntegerType
LongType = spark.sql.types.LongType.
```

One solution is to create 1 to 1 HashMap of String and spark.sql.types and use it while iterating the array. 
Is there any other cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just use scala pattern matching. Like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val typeList = inputArray.map(s => {
  s match {
    case "StringType" => StringType
    case "IntegerType" => IntegerType
    etc...
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("unknown type")  
  }
})
```